# Typo3 Admin Tools Section is missing in Backend

Tags: typo3

I am the new Admin from a Website and have never worked before with Typo3. When i am logged in as Admin, i cant see the "Admin Tools" and also the "Forms" section. But in the install tool the admin is set as "System Maintainer".

[image: Backend Screenshot]

[image: Install Tool Screenshot]

Typo3 Version: 10.4.21

How can I get Access to the Admin Tools?

Comment: Did you refresh the whole backend after you've added the system maintainer setting to that user? Or maybe relogin in a different browser? What happens if you create a new admin user in the TYPO3 Install Tool? By the way: you should avoid the username "admin" due to security reasons.

Comment: @PeterKraume What exactly do you mean by "refresh the whole backend"? You mean cleared the cache? Yes, that's what I did. I create a new admin in the install tool and log into the backend in a new browser, but its the same I don't see any admin tools.

Answer (score 0):

In typo3 there are admins and system maintainer. If at least one system maintainer is configured regular admins loose the rightd for the install tool. As some installations require a seperation in this regard

Comment: I have only entered one user as system maintainer as a test, but I still do not see any admin tools. Even after logging in again in a different browser, for example.